# 'My Files' folder keeps changing it's name by itself

Tags: android, directory

'My Files' folder keeps on changing it's name by itself on my Samsung galaxy note 10 plus.
It changes the name to 'Page %1$d of %2$d'

I can change the name of it but after restarting the phone it comes back again.

What should I do? Please, anyone help me.

Comment: First, this is off topic as its not about programming.  But there is no "My Files" folder in Android.  What you're looking at is some app Samsung put on there, and we have no clue what it's supposed to do, or what you did that you think should have changed its name.

Comment: invalid theme .............................................